# Get current controller in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `View - _Edit` which lives in `News M/V/C`.

I reuse the `V/M` via the `CategoryController` as:

```
return PartialView("/Views/News/_Edit.cshtml", model);
```

How from within the `View - _Edit` can I alert the controller name?

When I:

```
alert('@ViewContext. RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()');
```

The Value is: `News`
However, the URL is: `/Category/foobar`

Is there a way to get the value `'Category'` to alert? thanks

Comment: you don't have a `NewsController`?

Comment: Please post your action `method` that is loading the `partialview` and what `controller` that `method` exists in.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

I have put this in my partial view:

```
@HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()
```

in the same kind of situation you describe, and it shows the controller described in the URL (Category for you, Product for me), instead of the actual location of the partial view.

So use this alert instead:

```
alert('@HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()');
```

Comment: The answer below by Palpie is an (easier to remember) shortcut: `@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]`

Comment: Just an fyi, you don't need to get `HttpContext.Current`. `Request` is available directly.

Comment: Is it possible to get the full controller class name including namespace? Also it would be cool to also be able to show view name.

Comment: btw, `["action"]` works if you want the name of the action method.

Answer (score 124):

I do it like this:

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
```

Comment: Keep in mind that your solution will return the controller that is currently being executed. Hence, if a browser makes a request for ControllerA, and ControllerA renders a partial view from ControllerB, your solution would return ControllerB's name, while Nicholas Sizer solution would return ControllerA's name.

Comment: Should be accepted as the best answer.  This is working still in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Answer (score 21):

Create base class for all controllers and put here name attribute:

```
public abstract class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
}
```

In view

```
@{
    var controller = ViewContext.Controller as MyBaseController;
    if (controller != null)
    {
       @controller.Name
    }
}
```

Controller example

```
 public class SampleController: MyBaseController 
    { 
      public override string Name { get { return "Sample"; } 
    }
```

Comment: Please explain how the `Name` property gets set?

Answer (score 13):

Other way to get current Controller name in View

```
@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use:

```
ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Name
```

This will give you the whole Controller's Name

Answer (score 2):

You are still in the context of your `CategoryController` even though you're loading a `PartialView` from your `Views/News` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the below code to get the controller name

```cs
@HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

If you are using MVC 3 you can use

```
@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this nowadays (latest versions) of `ASP.NET Core MVC`, you can use:

```
@Context.Request.RouteValues["controller"].ToString()
```