# Getting controller name from razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I seem to be having a difficult getting something that should be easy. From within my view, using Razor, I'd like to get the name of the current controller. For example, if I'm here:

```
http://www.example.com/MyController/Index
```

How can I get the controller name, `MyController` from a Razor expression:

```
@* Obviously this next line doesn't work
    @Controller.Name
*@
```

I'm new to MVC, so if this is an obvious answer, don't attack me to bad.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852979/get-current-controller-in-view . Curious on your use-case though..

Comment: @Chandu - My website has a navigation menu that I'm building dynamically in razor using a constant List<T> and iterating through each item in that list using @@foreach in order to output the menu items. While its building the menu, I want it to apply a class called "selected" to the current page I'm on. For example, if I'm on "www.example.com/Home/Index" and it comes across the "Home" menu item, I want it to apply the class. I can post code if that'll help.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
@{ 
    var controllerName = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
}
```

OR

```
@{ 
    var controllerName = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 47):

An addendum to Koti Panga's answer: the two examples he provided are **not** equivalent.

This will return the name of the controller handling the view where this code is executed:

```
var handlingController = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

And this will return the name of the controller requested in the URL:

```
var requestedController = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

While these will certainly be the same in most cases, there are some cases where you might be inside a partial view belonging to a different controller and want to get the name of the controller "higher-up" in the chain, in which case the second method is required.

**For example,** imagine you have a partial view responsible for rendering the website's menu links. So for every page in your website, the links are prepared and passed to the view from an action called `SiteMenuPartial` in `LayoutController`.

So when you load up `/Home/Index`, the layout page is retrieved, the `SiteMenuPartial` method is called by the layout page, and the `SiteMenuPartial.cshtml` partial view is returned. If, in that partial view, you were to execute the following two lines of code, they would return the values shown:

```
/* Executes at the top of SiteMenuPartial.cshtml */
@{
    // returns "Layout"
    string handlingController = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

    // returns "Home"
    string requestedController = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 18):

```
@HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

MVC 3

```
@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue
```

MVC 4.5 Or MVC 5

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

To remove need for `ToString()` call use

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller")
```

Answer (score 4):

I want to add some more information to the previous answers. Maybe someone need.

In order to find `Area Name`, `Controller Name` and `Action Name` in razor view engine you can use:

```
@{
    var areaName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"].ToString();

    var controllerName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

    var actionName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also if you want to get the full controller's name (with "Controller" ending) you can use:

```
ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Name
```

Answer (score -6):

@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();