# Is there a way to integrate Tag Helpers into MVC CodeTemplates?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have just gotten started with ASP.NET MVC 5 (C#) and have been a little confused by the HTML helpers.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Song"))
```

I understand how this can be helpful, but feel that for people who do not know Razor/C#, that this will be a steep learning curve if not properly exposed. I am also aware of the Tag Helpers that are available and like what I see so far.

```
<form asp-action="Add" asp-controller="Song">
```

To me, this seems more appropriate, as it means that people who do not understand Razor syntax will be able to more easily read and understand what is happening, as it bears much more similarity to "normal" HTML. That being said, changing each page to use Tag Helpers seems monotonous and unnecessary.

I have recently found the CodeTemplate files, and included them in my project with the intention of adding the Tag Helpers in the template files. However, I soon realized that most Tag Helpers need a specific Controller or whatever to fill out the element attributes. Obviously, this Controller/whatever **will change** dynamically depending on which Controller/whatever prompted the creation of the View. If I hardcode `asp-controller="Song"` and then I try to create an Album View from this CodeTemplate, I obviously will have used the wrong controller.

Is there a way to access the dynamic property of whatever Controller, Link, etc called the View? In other words, is there someway of doing this in the CodeTemplate, where `This` is the Controller/whatever that constructs the View from the modified CodeTemplate?

```
<form asp-action="This.Action" asp-controller="This.Controller">
```

---

### Example:

If I had `<form asp-action="This.Action" asp-controller="This.Controller">` in my CodeTemplate in all Views, and then created the Views from different Controllers:

#### Song Controller

- Create View - `<form asp-action="Add" asp-controller="Song">`
- Update View - `<form asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Song">`

#### Album Controller

- Create View - `<form asp-action="Add" asp-controller="Album">`
- Update View - `<form asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Album">`

---

Is this possible at all? Or am I completely off? Let me know! Thanks!

Comment: This is totally off topic but I just wanted to touch a little bit on why razor can be useful... Lets say you have your model and in that model you have something like "public string FirstName { get; set;}" and then you want to give that value by having the user input something in a textbox. With razor syntax it's as simple as doing this: 
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.FirstName) 
That gives you your text box, and it will give value to the FirstName property in your model. The learning curve really isn't big and if you get  a job doing MVC it's likely they'll be using razor.

Comment: Completely agree. That's probably how I'd use Razor. But I think for some things that using the Tag Helpers would be better. But perhaps it's a bad idea to mix and match styles?

Comment: I'm sure someone more 'senior' can correct me or chime in here but personally I've never seen it done in the different codebases that I've worked with. Razor just seems to be where it's at right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [solution I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415875/getting-controller-name-from-razor).

```
<form asp-controller="@this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())" 
  asp-action="@this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString())">
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I haven't dealt with ASP.NET pretty much since 2015. Hopefully this can help someone else though! Cheers!