# How can I set up conditional Layouts with _ViewStart in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I want to display different layouts based on the current rendered Page.

I can't find anything online about this but I feel like this should be an extremely common use case.

I only have a few pages. I would like to assign unique layouts to both my Register and Login pages.

This is what I've got so far but I am unable to use the ControllerContext in this situation.

```
@{
    string controllerName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    dynamic Layout;
    switch (controllerName)
    {
        case "Register":
            Layout = "_RegisterLayout";
            break;
        case "Login":
            Layout = "_LoginLayout";
            break;
        default:
            Layout = "_Layout";
            break;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What problem you are facing with this code? Are you getting any error?

Comment: The screenshot shows why it does not compile.

Comment: You can set Layout in individual pages instead of using ViewStart

Comment: Would you recommend deleting ViewStart entirely and instead setting the layout on each page?

Comment: You might want to use ViewStart for other pages to set layout for them while override Layout for login and register page

Comment: Can you provide some code on how to override Layout for different pages? Also, how can I create a new Layout page? Can I do so by clicking Add > Razor Page?

Comment: You can get the controller name in ViewStart by using ViewContext. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415875/getting-controller-name-from-razor

Comment: I get the following error ``NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.``

Answer (score 4):

We recently ran into a similar problem. We decided to provide the layout name with ViewData, Here's how.

```
Layout = (string)ViewData["LayoutName"] ?? "DefaultLayout";
```

This way you can change the layout using the action, or from inside the view or using an Action filter. I will include an Action filter that does the following using the Controller name, like you asked, and then you can register the filter globally.

```
    public class LayoutNameFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            var result = context.Result as ViewResult;
            var controllerName = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            switch (controllerName)
            {
                case "Register":
                    result.ViewData["LayoutName"] = "_RegisterLayout";
                    break;
                case "Login":
                    result.ViewData["LayoutName"] = "_LoginLayout";
                    break;
                default:
                    result.ViewData["LayoutName"] = "_Layout";
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
        }
    }
```

And then you can register this filter globally by replacing the services.AddMvc like this.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new SampleFilter());
            })
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not using MVC unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

As a convenience, the _ViewStart file is used to set the layout for all pages in the same folder as the ViewStart, and all its subfolders. You can override that in a number of ways, but the simplest way in your case is to specify a different value for the `Layout` property in the Razor Page itself:

```
@page
@model MyApp.Pages.Account.LoginModel
@{
    Layout = "/path/to/login-layout.cshtml;
}
<h1>Login</h1>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above did not solve the issue for me but the solution below works for me using .net 5 razor pages.

**Note:** i set the layout page based on the pages folder

the RelativePath gives you the url relative path like "/Pages/Admin/Index.cshtml" then i split the path to string array. from the array i get the
folder name using pathArray[2].

```
var path = ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.CompiledPageActionDescriptor)ViewContext.ActionDescriptor).RelativePath;
string[] pathArray = path.Split('/');
string pageFolder = pathArray[2];
if (pageFolder != null && pageFolder.ToLower()=="admin")
{
    Layout = "_AdminLayout";
}
else
{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

**UPDATE:**
This still works in .NET 6

Answer (score 0):

You can try with ViewData. In the following code, I have changed the layout only for the contact page

Contact.cshtml.cs

```
    public void OnGet()
    {
        ViewData["page"] = "Contact";
        Message = "Your contact page.";
    }
```

_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{

    if (ViewData["page"] != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewData["page"].ToString()))
    {
        Layout = "_ContactLayout";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "_Layout";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `_ViewStart.cshtml` file :

```
@{
    if(ViewData["Layout"] == "Layout1")
        Layout = "_Layout";
    else Layout = "_Layout2";
}
```

That is an example that is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Another great option is to use **sections**!  If you do not want to completely redo your `_Layout` or you do not want to have duplicate code in several different layout files.

Here is a section I made in my Layout:

```
<main role="main" class="pb-3">

    @* PageHeader is used if you want to put something outside of the bootstrap container. *@
    @await RenderSectionAsync("PageHeader", false);

    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</main>
```

Then in a different view file, I can render a section like this:

```
@section PageHeader
{
    <section class="container-fluid bg-light py-3">
    ...
    </section>
}
```