# pass parameters to current controller from _layout.cshtml

Tags: model-view-controller

I use a _layout.cshtml file that have a language selection, when the user change language I need to only pass lang=gb. Since this layout is applied to several views/controllers I need to pass the lang parameter to the view/controller that is currently rendered. What helper method do I use then?

Comment: I dont follow... I tried the @Url.Action helper first but there you need to specify controller and action and since thelayout.cshtml is the same for all controllers that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This post helped me out [Getting controller name from razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415875/getting-controller-name-from-razor)

There I could get the current controller and pass the lang parameter like this..
href="~/@controllerName?lang=gb"