# How to edit a CSS class in the MVC Layout view using C#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm wondering how I can change the class that is assigned to an element in the layout view from the C# code within the controller?

In my nav bar I have a css class that is set as active when viewing the page but obviously I need to change this when I change views (pages) but i'm not sure on the best way to do this within mvc

Comment: How are you generated the HTML element?

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the current controller name and action as detailed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852979/get-current-controller-in-view) and use that information in your layout to choose which element should be "active".

Or in a simple application another common way to do this is to use the `ViewBag` and set a property with the name of the current page.

In your controller method include the following.

```
ViewBag.CurrentPageName = "HomePage";
```

Your Razor (MVC3+) view code can consume this information and set the appropriate class on an element.

```
@{
  string pageName = ViewBag.CurrentPageName ?? "Unknown";
}

if(pageName == "HomePage"){
   //Output your DOM element with the appropriate class name for the "active" link.
}
```

OR

```
<a href="#" class="@(pageName == "HomePage" ? "active" : string.Empty)>Home Page</a>
```

For MVC2 and older you'll need to use TempData, but the concept is similar.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to bind CSS values to model or viewbag

for example

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Value1, new { @class = ViewBag.value1Class })
```

or may be

```
<div class="@Model.Class1 @Model.Class2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery maybe?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#mainPageDiv").removeClass()
                     .addClass('newClass'); 
});
```

Put this in view, not layout.