# Test IsAuthorizationRequired from Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In short how do you check if authorization is required from a razor view?

NOTE: `@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` won't do it. I'm not interested in whether a user is authenticated or authorized - but rather if a page requires authorization / authentication at a 'global' (well layout) level.

Let's say there are 2 controllers, like so:

```
[Authorize]
public class SecretController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SecretClue()
    {
        return View("oo lala");
    }

    public ActionResult Secret()
    {
        return View("Jane kissed ...");
    }
}


public class RecipesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult RoastBoar()
    {
        return View("One wild boar...");
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult SecretSauce()
    {
        return View("Mustard, mixed with...");
    }
}
```

How would I, from the `_Layout` razor view, determine if the page requires authorization / authentication, such that when it does the `<p>Remember SHHHH!</p>` line is shown?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
    <div>
        @if (ViewBag.IsAuthenticationRequired ?? false)
        {
            <p>Remember SHHHH!</p> 
        }
    </div>
</body>
```

Please don't ask why I want to do this, just answer the question if you can.

Comment: SDK - this has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Comment: @Paul - sorry tagging in a rush

Comment: Are you aware that if you do need authorisation and you don't have authorisation, you wont get the page?  (I'm assuming this is the case, just asking).   In which case, should your question read:  "determine if a page *required* authorization / authentication" / "check if authorization *was* required"

Comment: Can you make any changes to your code other than the .cshtml?   Easiest option is to extend `[Authorize]`

Comment: @freedomn-m yes I'm aware of that - this is a quick and dirty way of dealing with Bearer Token / Cookie Authentication mismatch. I'm sure there are better ways, but I'll get to that later when time permits.

Answer (score 0):

As so often happens this is a solution, I'd welcome other simpler solutions...

```
public class IsAuthorizationRequiredFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public IsAuthorizationRequiredFilter() { }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        bool isAuthorizationRequired = !filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true)
                      && !filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true)
                      && (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), inherit: true)
                      || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), inherit: true));

        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.AuthenticationRequired = isAuthorizationRequired;
    }

    private bool IsValid(string key)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: An alternative is to use an `ActionFilter` and use reflection to check for `Authorize` attribute on the `filterContext.ControllerDescription` - but I wouldn't have said it was 'simpler' than extending `AuthorizationFilter`

Comment: Also, much less elegant, from the view, you can get the controller context and again use reflection - directly from the .cshtml (so no need to add attributes to your controllers etc).   Breaks the *MVC* paradigm and leaves a bad taste in the mouth, but if it fits your requirements.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852979/get-current-controller-in-view